# A reference for Wagner's Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors

In the course of a project I am developing I have to use a classical result in topological graph theory due to Wagner in which Wagner gives the precise structure of graphs in which $K_5$ is excluded as a minor.

The result (which follows the lines of his proof when excluding $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$) is in german in the original paper of Wagner (see reference [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01594196)). So my question is that if someone knows if there exists a modern version of this result and, if possible, in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A text book reference is [Graph Decompositions: A Study in Infinite Graph Theory](https://archive.org/details/graphdecompositi0000dies/page/178/mode/2up) by Reinhard Diestel (1990), see chapter 6.